# Cannot set the right position by text around circle

Tags: inkscape

I want my text to run around a circle, but I cannot set it properly.

If I center align it, then it shows the whole text, but 90° ccw rotated.

[image]

If I left align it, then it cuts the text by 180° and half of the last word is lost.

[image]

Any idea how to do this properly?

Comment: It's been a while since I've spent much time in Inkscape, so perhaps this is a facile question, but in your first example with the 90 CCW rotation of the text on a  path, can't you then just rotate the geometric figure / path to correctly re-align your text?

Comment: @GerardFalla I could do that too, but I think I'll do this in SVG instead. I am a lot closer to programming than drawing... Doing it with applications that don't work properly is beyond frustrating for me. I tried out GIMP too, it was even worse. It would be a few clicks in PS as far as I remember, but I don't have license.

Comment: Rotate the circle. You can use a horizontal guide or a rectangle to more easily see if the text ends at the same height on both sides.

Comment: @Moini Thanks, I rotated the circle, now it is ok. :-) Can you add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotate the circle. You can use a horizontal guide or a rectangle to more easily see if the text ends at the same height on both sides.

(I like Billy Kerr's arc option a lot, too)

Comment: Ye, me too, but rotating the circle was a lot easier for me. I am a beginner with this app...

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

[image]

The circle is converted to path and broken to open path at the six o'clock node

The text isn't freely typed, the frame for it was drawn at first and Align Middle is ON.

Selecting both and going to Text > Put on Path makes this:

[image]

Breaking the path at 6 o'clock forces the available space to start at 6 o'clock. It and mid alignment make the result symmetric with **zero** manual adjustments

Answer (score 2):

You can use the arc control points on a circle to control the location of the text.

See this for example:

[image]

Even if the stroke of the circle has been set to none, you can still select it using the XML Editor, and then edit the control points.

[image]